# Question on calculating character sums

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, fourier-analysis, characters

I am wondering if there are any references that would help me with the following problem:

Let $p>2$ be a prime number, $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ odd such that $(n,p)=1$, $\chi$ an imaginary quadratic character of conductor $n$, and $\omega$ the Teichmuller character.

I'm trying to calculate the sum
\begin{equation}
\sum_{a=1}^{(np-1)/2} \chi\omega^{-1}(a)(-1)^a.
\end{equation}

This sum almost reminds me of a quadratic Gauss sum (I know this is a big stretch) which I've seen can be computed using Fourier analysis.  From my basic understanding (see [Rodgers - Fourier series, Gauss sums, and quadratic reciprocity](https://mast.queensu.ca/%7Ebr66/421/gauss_sums_handout.pdf)), the computation relies on the fact that
\begin{equation}
\sum_{a=0}^{p-1}\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)e^{2\pi  i a/p} = \sum_{a=0}^{p-1} e^{2\pi i a^2/p}
\end{equation}
(here $(a/p)$ is the Legendre symbol) and defining $f(x) = \sum_{a=0}^{p-1} e^{2\pi i (a+x)^2/p}$, which is periodic on $\mathbb{R}$, we compute $\hat{f}(x)$ and find that
\begin{equation}
\sum_{a=0}^{p-1}\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)e^{2\pi  i a/p}= \sum_{a = -\infty}^{\infty}\hat{f}(a) = \text{a computable integral}.
\end{equation}

In my naive attempt to mimic this process, I think I fail (or just can't see how) to write $\sum_{a=1}^{(np-1)/2} \chi\omega^{-1}(a)(-1)^a$ as a sum involving only exponentials and then coming up with a periodic function $f(x)$ that is my character sum when evaluated at 0.  Because it is quite a stretch to compare my sum to a Gauss sum, I'm now thinking it is a bad idea to try to mimic this computation.

**Questions:**

- Is there a more general method out there for computing character sums like the one I have using Fourier analysis?
- Are there any other methods/theory that might help me out in calculating this sum?

I would also be happy if I could somehow factor this sum in $\mathbb{Q}(e^{2\pi i/(p-1)})$.  I'm reminded of Stickelberger's theorem, where part of the proof involves finding the prime factorization of a certain Gauss sum (here I go again with the comparison).  I know that the sum I'm looking at will not behave as nicely as the Gauss sum in the proof of Stickelberger's, but I am wondering,

- Is there is a general theory for finding the $\mathcal{P}$-adic valuation of a character sum, where $\mathcal{P}$ lies above $p$ in whatever field the character sum lives in.

Comment: Using the Chinese remainder theorem, doesn't your sum factor into a product of two independent Gauss sums ?

Comment: @HenriCohen Doesn't summing up to $(np-1)/2$ mess up the Chinese remainder theorem since it is an isomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}/np\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Since both $\chi$ and $\omega$ are odd characters, the sum to $np-1$ is twice that up to $(np-1)/2$, or do I misunderstand ?

Comment: @HenriCohen I think the alternating part messes that up since $(-1)^{np-a} = (-1)(-1)^a$, so summing up to $np-1$ gives you zero.

Comment: sorry, indeed since you assume $n$ odd.

Comment: What do you mean by "calculate" here? If you want to bound the sum you can do a Polya-Vinogradov method. I don't see any evidence that there is a formula for the sum simpler than what you have here.

Comment: @WillSawin By calculate I mean finding an exact value like you can do for quadratic Gauss sums.  I realize this might be hoping for too much. My real concern is what kind of $p$ make this sum zero mod $p$.  An example of what I have in mind is $\sum_{\substack{a=1 \\ p \nmid a}}^{np} \chi(a)(-1)^a = (1 - \chi(p))\sum_{a = 1}^{n-1}\chi(a)(-1)^a$.  So one condition I get is $\sum_{\substack{a=1 \\ p \nmid a}}^{np} \chi(a)(-1)^a =0 $ if $p$ splits in the field associated to $\chi$.  I would like to do something similar here, so I don't need to calculate this sum exactly (but it would be nice).